# Maven, stability, use v3 or use v2?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-automation, maven-3

We are starting project and can't decide which version of maven to use. Maven v3 come up with very good [features](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3908561/Top-10-New-Features-in-Maven-3.htm), but other side v3 seems have more unfixed bugs [from codehaus jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3aissues-panel)(see Unresolved: By Version). And we can't say that v2 is outdated.

Can we say that v2 more stable, it means less pitfalls,we will lose lees time than v3?

Maybe, some recommendations from personal experience.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/02/top-ten-reasons-to-move-to-maven-3/

Comment: Good article, I already read that, but when introducing new version of something it always seems as panacea. I have habit to wait for SOMESOFTWARE version X.1 or X.2 to sure that is working correctly.

Comment: Well it was [released two years ago](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/10/maven-30-released) so I wouldn't say that it is bleeding edge to use v3 now.

Comment: Considered writing your Pom.xml so both will work?

Comment: Compatibility both versions, good idea. Gives us opportunity to use v3 features when we need. For example performance and parallel builds.

Comment: You could also consider using [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from over a year of extensive use of maven in several middle-sized and large projects I can say that most often you come across some issues in maven plugins, not in maven itself.

Originally, we've been using version 2.2.1 (and we're still using it at the moment), but I already made all of our projects compatible with maven 3 (so one can build them both with 2-nd and 3-rd versions of maven). Migration went pretty smooth, I should say, though there were issues that had to be fixed.

Maven 3 indeed has more unfixed bugs but I think that is mostly because of the 2 reasons: a) more people use maven 3 than maven 2; b) maven 2 has been on the market for a long-long time. I also remember reading somewhere that there won't be any new features introduced in maven 2 over time (there's only going to be a maintenance release 2.2.2).

To sum it up, if I were starting new project, I'd definitely go with maven 3.